# mirroring antenna symbol in CircuiTikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

I want to change the left to right `antenna` to right to left one as the receiver requires mirror image of transmitting antenna.

This is my simplified code

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\tikzstyle{block} = [draw, fill=white, rectangle, 
    minimum height=3em, minimum width=4em]
\tikzstyle{input} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{output} = [coordinate]
\tikzstyle{pinstyle} = [pin edge={to-,t,black}]
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
\node[block](tx){transmitter};
\node[antenna,right of =tx,xshift=-0.8 cm] {};
\node[block,right of =tx,xshift=5 cm](rx){reciver};
\node[antenna,left of =rx] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please, show us a small code with the symbol so we can compile it.

Comment: this is my simplified code

Comment: put `xscale=-1` as in `\node[antenna,xscale=-1,] at (rx.west) {};`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Also suggested: [How do you accept an answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `xscale=-1` to mirror the antenna along the `x`-direction.

Here is the refined code where I have used the proper syntax for `positioning` library and `\tikzset` instead of `tikzstyle` (which is deprecated).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\tikzset{block/.style = {draw, fill=white, rectangle,
                  minimum height=3em, minimum width=2cm},
        input/.style = {coordinate},
        output/.style = {coordinate},
        pinstyle/.style = {pin edge={to-,t,black}}
    }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance=2cm,>=latex']
\node[block](tx){transmitter};
\node[antenna] at (tx.east) {};
\node[block,right = 5cm of tx](rx){receiver};
\node[antenna,xscale=-1] at (rx.west) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 You beat me to it! :P I was writing the answer while you commented and answered. By the way, some corrections I had done in my code: "reciver" is misspelled. I know it was in the OP's code but it should be fixed. Also the libraries can be listed in the same command, therefore saving space. By the way I tried to use `right=5cm of...` in mine, but it wasn't working (oddly).

Comment: How to reduce the height of antenna?